# Python: How to code empty filedsin csv file as numerically ascending

Tags: python

I have a csv file and a dictionary like this:

```
myData={'ID':'','Name':'','Age':''}
```

I can read and write my Values from the csv file into `myData`

I would like to have the column ID numerically ascending.

```
'ID' 'Name'
1 Maria
2 Jones
3 Jack
```

How can i do this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you explain in more details? what do you want to do? also include the code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: as a sidenote, if your dictionary's values are all `''`, you could just use a set. `myData={'ID','Name','Age'}   `

Comment: Sure.
I have a csv file and a dictionary like this:

.
.
...
'for row in reader:
'myData={'ID':'','Name':'','Age':''}'
with open('test.csv', 'a') as data:
        for value in myData.values():
            data.write('{}|'.format(value))'

Comment: Does your dictionary `myData` contain empty values for all keys?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma just the column 'ID' is empty (in the csv file). Because i just wanted to know if my code can insert the numbers (ascending) automatically.

Comment: Can you show the sample of your `csv` file?

Comment: ID Name Age
 Maria 15
 Jones 30
 Jones 25

Comment: @m1711 I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, Use:

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as r, open("output.csv", 'w') as w:
    reader = csv.DictReader(r, fieldnames=["ID", "Name", "Age"], delimiter=" ")
    writer = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=["ID", "Name", "Age"], delimiter=" ")
    writer.writeheader()

    for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
        if idx == 0:
            continue # skip header

        row["ID"] = idx
        writer.writerow(row)
```

For example if the contents of `input.csv` file looks like:

```
ID Name Age
 Maria 15
 Jones 30
 Jones 25
```

Then the above code will produce the `output.csv` which looks like:

```
ID Name Age
1 Maria 15
2 Jones 30
3 Jones 25
```